# AS3 Possible to check if mask is completely filled?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mask, fill, erase

With brush_mc you can brush over a mask, which turns the pixels to transparent in brush strokes.
So visually it erases the mask and the masked movieclip appears.
I want to trace, if the mask is completely turned transparent.

Is it possible to check if the mask is turned completely transparent without bitmapdata?

```
// this creates a mask that hides the movieclip on top
var mask_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mask_mc)

//assign the mask to the movieclip it should 'cover'
mc1.mask = mask_mc;

//add event listeners for the 'brush'
brush_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,brushDown);
brush_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,brushUp);

//function to drag the brush over the mask
function brushDown(dragging:MouseEvent):void{
    dragging.currentTarget.startDrag();
    MovieClip(dragging.currentTarget).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,erase) ;
    mask_mc.graphics.moveTo(brush_mc.x,brush_mc.y);
}

//function to stop dragging the brush over the mask
function brushUp(dragging:MouseEvent):void{
    dragging.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    MovieClip(dragging.currentTarget).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,erase);
}

//fill the mask with transparant pixels so the movieclip turns visible
function erase(e:Event):void{
    with(mask_mc.graphics){
        beginFill(0x000000);
        drawRect(brush_mc.x,brush_mc.y,brush_mc.width,brush_mc.height);
        endFill(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to As3, so the explanations could be a bit off, but that's to make it more clear for my self. Feel free to correct me

Comment: why do you not want to use bitmapdata?

Comment: @grapefrukt I'd like to use it, but I thought if it could be done with only mask it would be easier to understand. However, I tried some things with bitmapdata, but can't get it to work. If you have any suggestions, more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) and look a tthe compare function.
 
What you need to do is create a second bitmapdata object the same size as your mask but with full transparent 0x00000000. Then use the compare function. As the docs say.

> If the BitmapData objects are equivalent (with the same width, height,
>   and identical pixel values), the method returns the number 0.

[EDIT]

```
var myTestingBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mask_mc.width, mask_mc.height, true, 0x00000000);

// this is untested code but you might have to comvert mask_mc to bitmapdata
trace( myTestingBitmapData.compare( mask_mc) )
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, is it correct to assign one bitmapdata to the mask like this; myBitmapData.draw(mask_mc); ?
Now it stays at 0, so no diffrence yet.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer. It may not work for your situation but atleast you will get the idea on how to test. if the trace is 0 then there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably implement some form of counter that keeps tracks of the mask's state.

The idea would be to check the state of the mask before a brush action. You have a total number of pixels to start with, then add or substract from the counter depending on the pixel's color.

When your counter reaches a certain value, your mask is erased.

This is not an ideal solution though since your mask may look like it's been erased but you'd still have a few random pixels that keep the counter under the necessary value, so you may have to average a little... whether with the brush action or with the counter.